# Send and receive Fax with Windows Fax

Tags: c#, windows, fax

Windows 7 has built in Fax Application. Would it be possible to connect to this and send fax over Windows Fax (put a outgoing Fax in the Outgoing Folder) and read all received Faxes?
I have to use C# to do this. When it is possible, are there any samples which are showing this?

Comment: ??? - When I translate "Heute sind 30 Faxe bei mir eingegangen." in Google from German to English, I get "Today 30 faxes are received by me."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fxscom.dll in from WINDOWS\system32 directory.

if it is not there you will need to install fax services from windows components

Here is an example how to use that library [Faxing with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Fax-XP-ing.aspx)

Because it is a COM object you will find reference to it under COM Tab.  After you add reference to it you should have reference to FAXCOMLib library.

Comment: Thanks. When I try this, I get always the Exception "Invalid Operation" when I try to send the fax. Have you any idea about this?

Comment: Please post full stack trace.

Comment: Die Daten sind unzulässig. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007000D)
ErrorCode -2147024883 int
   bei FAXCOMLib.IFaxDoc.Send()
   bei Fax_Application.MainForm.SendFax(String DocumentName, String FileName, String RecipientName, String FaxNumber) in C:\Temp\Fax-XP-ing_src\Fax Application\MainForm.cs:Zeile 260.
I use Windows 7

Comment: Translating 0x8007000D - ERROR_INVALID_DATA, however you are saying about Invalid Operation which means security issue.  Maybe when you are calling COM interop you need to change some security settings.

Answer (score 0):

I use now FaxMan SDK. It isn't cheap but do all what I nead.