# How can I send a fax with my Qt application?

Tags: c++, windows, api, fax

I have a Qt application which needs to be able to send faxes. I'm wondering if there are any fax libraries I can make use of. I haven't been able to find an obvious solution, so I would appreciate your help.

The application has to run on windows xp / windows 7.

If I am unclear/you need more information, please let me know.

**EDIT**

There will be a fax machine. I'm not sure how the fax drivers work, but the application should support every fax machine.

Comment: DO you have a fax machine or are you planning to use an internet fax service

Comment: I will be using a fax machine.

Comment: How are faxes normally sent from a computer? Don't they use the same interface as printers? If so, you could simply use `QPrinterDialog` and select the correct device.

Comment: @Laurent I need the fax to be sent automatically. No user action

Comment: A related question [Send and receive fax with Windows Fax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684079/send-and-receive-fax-with-windows-fax?rq=1)

Comment: @PTBG, in that case, you can simply use `QPrinter`, which will let you set everything programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has a Fax Service Extended COM API

Complete with code samples.

Configuration
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692969(v=vs.85).aspx

Sending
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693482(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd make sure your installed fax has a printer driver, that lets you print to it. Then use the QT print API: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/printing.html

I'd try it with the print dialog first, and choose the fax machine manually.

Then check through all the data in [QPrinter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qprinter.html)

To see which one has the fax number. I would hope that it might be the [OutPutFileName](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qprinter.html#outputFileName).

---

The other way might be to use Microsoft Scripting to send the fax, wrapped in the [QtActiveX module](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qaxcontainer-module.html)

---

Finally I googled this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693482(v=vs.85).aspx

---

Sorry it's not a complete answer. I hope it can point you in the right direction though.